# Dict comprehension, tuples and lazy evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, functional-programming

I am trying to see if I can pull off something quite *lazy* in Python.

I have a dict comprehension, where the value is a tuple. I want to be able to create the second entry of the tuple by using the first entry of the tuple.

An example should help.

```
dictA = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 42}
{key: (a = someComplexFunction(value), moreComplexFunction(a)) for key, value in dictA.items()}
```

Is it possible that the `moreComplexFunction` uses the calculation in the first entry of the tuple?

Comment: You can have `someComplexFunction` implement an [`lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), then you can just call `moreComplexFunction(someComplexFunction(value))` and not get the performance hit.  There *is* some overhead in caching and it's probably overkill if you're only using the cache once, so I'm making this a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could add a second loop over a one-element tuple:

```
{key: (a, moreComplexFuntion(a)) for key, value in dictA.items() 
                                 for a in (someComplexFunction(value),)}
```

This gives you access to the output of `someComplexFunction(value)` in the value expression, but that's rather ugly.

Personally, I'd move to a regular loop in such cases:

```
dictB = {}
for key, value in dictA.items():
    a = someComplexFunction(value)
    dictB[key] = (a, moreComplexFunction(a))
```

and be done with it.

Comment: Martijn, thanks. This seems like a reasonable thing to want to do (at least to me). Obviously for clarity the loop is better. It would be nice to have a clever language feature that I could exploit for this though. :)

Comment: My +1 is for the regular loop. The code is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: the clever language feature is 'lambda functions', which are part of the functional programming toolsuite and would let you embed that function i.e. {key: (lambda x: (x, moreComplexFunction(x)))(someComplexFunction(value)) for key, value in dictA.items()}. but it's uglier, hard to read, and slower. the loop is easy to read and likely to be the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

or, you could just write a function to return the tuple:

```
def kv_tuple(a):
    tmp = someComplexFunction(a)
    return (a, moreComplexFunction(tmp))

{key:kv_tuple(value) for key, value in dictA.items()}
```

this also gives you the option to use things like namedtuple to get names for the tuple items, etc. I don't know how much faster/slower this would be though... the regular loop is likely to be faster (fewer function calls)...

Comment: You know, this is what I ended up doing, but I wanted something that would use a neat feature of Python's functional programming model.

Comment: @fgnu: Creating a function *just* to use a comprehension hurts efficiency and is obfuscating. Just put the loop in the function.

Comment: @eryksun - it could be obfuscating, or it could be simpler. for me, keeping the statements shorter makes them easier for me to read (and like i said, i'd prefer named tuple here). `kv_tuple` isn't a very descriptive name, but i don't know what it's used for... could easily give it a name such that the above statement is more clearly generating X data from the Y data in dictA (and a function wrapping that would be even easier to read). unless there's a good reason to use `kv_tuple` elsewhere in the code, i agree, i'd probably go with the loop too.

Comment: no, i definitely agree it's slower.... just not that it's necessarily harder to understand.

Comment: The italics in my first comment implied that this would be a one-time use function. That's why I suggested moving the loop into an explicit function -- if the point is to make the code easier to understand. Then that function can be called in an expression just like using a comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Alongside [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909888/1142167), using a generator expression and a dict comprehension is also quite semantic and lazy:

```
dictA = { ... } # Your original dict

partially_computed = ((key, someComplexFunction(value))
                      for key, value in dictA.items())

dictB = {key: (a, moreComplexFunction(a)) for key, a in partially_computed}
```

Comment: This is just another form of introducing an extra loop :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is exactly what I thought!

Comment: Why yes, yes it is >.<. I think it generally solves the "ugliness" problem though.